Can a hyphen be a "letter" in some words?
Someone claims to me that the hyphen in the word "Uh-oh" is a letter, not a punctuation mark, because it represents a phonological instruction (the glottal stop). Is this true? I have never heard of hyphen being a letter in under certain conditions, neither did I find anything suggesting it can be when googling, but i might not be googling the correct terms.

Please add a few examples of what you googled, to prevent contributors covering the same ground. // Characters include letters plus numerals, punctuation marks .... Dictionary definitions don't seem to allow hyphens as letters. At least one such should be presented.

Have you googled what a letter is? It should be easy to find a definition.

@EdwinAshworth Unicode includes more than 26,000 characters that have the property General_Category=Letter, of which more than 300 have with the property General_Category=Modifier_Letter. Of these latter, many do resemble diacritics or punctuation marks but are considered letters all the same. However, none clearly looks like a hyphen, and we do not encode words like uh‐oh using  any of them anyway. See also Bringhurst.

A hyphen can be part of the spelling of a word (e.g. "well-known", "re-sign"), as you observe. But that doesn't mean it's a letter when used so.

The glottal stop occurs with or without the hyphen, that's just how the two components need to be pronounced together without blending together. It's not a phonological instruction, it denotes a compound.

Have you tried saying 'uh', or 'oh', or, for than matter 'orange' or 'oops without a glottal stop?  It cannot be done.  The hyphen has nothing to do with how we pronounce the word 'oh.  What it does is to tie the two exclamations into a single exclamation.

And if I use hard attack I have to write it “-uh-oh”?

@Servaes you mean like in https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/le-a/ ?

The full answer to this question is "No".  (The comments you mention from your friend, are, incoherent and totally nonsensical on every level.)

Here are a couple of questions which you might consider.  If the hyphen in front of 'oh' is an instruction to use a glottal stop, why is there no hyphen before "uh"?  In this case, spelling is being used to write down what we say.  "Uhoh" looks as weird as it sounds, because the 'uh' and the 'oh' are separated, but very slightly.  The hyphen shows that are to be taken as close together but fractionally  separate.  That is what hyphens tend to do.

@Tuffy. while I normally begin those words with a glottal stop, it is certainly not impossible to say them without it.

.WGroleau  Well, we all can when the initial vowel follows a preceding consonant in the same or previous word.  But I do not think it is possible without involuntarily interpolating aspiration, as in '(h)oh'.

I can imagine a computer form to fill out, with instruction: "Surname, limited to ten letters (including hyphens and apostrophes) _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _"

It depends on what you mean by ‘letter’.
But that gets tricky. Is ‘ç’ a letter in English? How about ‘ï’ or ‘ô’ or ‘ü’? They’re found in some English words (or at least, they used to be, English has lost most of the diacritical marks it inherited in loan words, as well as the few it had originally, for multiple reasons), and the presence of the diacritics does alter pronunciation from the ‘norm’ for English. And then you get actual letters like Æ or ð that were used historically but aren’t anymore. And at least early on, & was categorized as a letter (you can still find some old needlework samplers with the alphabet that include it).
And that’s just looking at English, it gets even more complicated when you consider other languages. For example, Arabic and Hebrew don’t consider tashkīl or niqqud respectively as letters, even though they definitely encode phonetic information that is crucial for correct pronunciation.
And that Arabic/Hebrew example is really instructive, because it showcases the reality that a ‘letter’ is largely what people who use the language agree it is. And for English that means that of the things I mentioned above (ç, ï, ô, ü, Æ and ð), none are considered letters in modern English (the first four are existing letters with diacritical marks, Æ is a ligature, and ð is uncategorized), and the same applies to hyphens because they are treated solely as punctuation.

As an aside, it’s debatable whether the hyphen is what’s encoding the glottal stop. The first ‘h’ could fit that purpose just as well, as could the simple separation of the syllables (note that ‘uh-oh’ is also written as ‘uh oh’ and pronounced exactly the same way).

Speaking of Hebrew and Arabic it is worth noting that these do have letters for a glottal stop, and treat it as a consonant.

Interestingly enough, in German, ä, ö, and ü are considered to be distinct letters, or at least that was the case when I was taught German about 40 years ago.

@BenHocking The same is generally true of other Germanic languages (though the set of letters is different, for example ä, ö, and å in Swedish or æ, ø, and å in Norweigian), and seems to be the case to some extent for many Uralic and Turkic languages as well (again with different sets of letters). English largely inherited it’s treatment of diacritical marks from French though, which generally does not see things like Ç, Î, or Æ as distinct letters.

Nobody has ever passed a law or established a multinational treaty decreeing what is or isn’t a letter. But there is an essentially universal convention that English has exactly 26 letters, and those particular 26 symbols do not include the hyphen.
Your informant is, of course, welcome to use whatever definition of letter they may wish. But they are not empowered to oblige anyone else to adopt their idiosyncratic usage of the word.

Some still use the æsc and the ethel.

Hysterically true.

And clearly the apostrophe in Hawai'i is a letter.

As is the acute accent in risqué, @PeterShor. We’re not talking the accented vowel, é, but the accent itself.

Things like the Hawaiian ʻokina and the ! in various Khoisan languages are letters in those languages. Although are they letters in English? There are also symbols such as apostrophes (forward or backward) used in romanizations of Arabic (not in Arabic script); it's less clear if they count as letters or not. Some romanizations of Chinese and Japanese use apostrophes to mark syllable breaks; I think most people would agree they're not letters.

Arguably, ç, used by some in the English loan-word facade/façade, is a separate letter from c. It's certainly a single character. // Apparently, the Danish [etc] letter ø is not used in English words, but is considered a different letter in that language [Danish has the Latin alphabet plus æ, ø, and å]. As is å, even with its disjoint sections.

'[T]here is an essentially universal convention that English has exactly 26 letters' (leaving aside archaisms such as æ): I agree, but this needs supporting references. In Danish, ø is considered to be an additional letter to the 26-letter Latin alphabet ... and oste and øste are, I believe, distinct words. 'Re-pair' and 'repair' are seen as different single words in English.  There are grey areas, when one looks below the surface, that need addressing.

@EdwinAshworth, added a link to the Wikipedia article entitled English Alphabet. Not exactly authoritative, but as I state in my answer, there is no authority to decree any definition.

Saying "Nobody has ever passed a law or established a multinational treaty decreeing what is or isn’t a letter" won't work. There are international standards about this, and the Unicode Consortium is quite solid about what is and is not a letter.

Come on, @tchrist, the Unicode Consortium maintains a standard for IT interoperability. They are no more “in charge” of what is or isn’t a letter in the English alphabet than anybody else is. Our writing system, and in particular our alphabet, is a convention and nothing more. Nobody has any authority to decree its makeup. And anyway, all Unicode does is standardize how the letters are represented digitally; it does not dictate what elements constitute the alphabet.

@tchrist I think it's clear from the OP that when Paul says "letter", he means "1) a symbol usually written or printed representing a speech sound and constituting a unit of an alphabet" rather than "5a) a single piece of type".
It's clear from the Unicode categories that they relates to the latter. For example, they have a separate character for ᴝ ("Latin Small Letter Sideways U"), which isn't a separate letter in the alphabet from regular "u".

@anotherdave OP may have a certain stipulative definition in mind, but it behooves answerers on ELU to go beyond a simplistic answer and address issues comprehensively (this includes pointing out degrees of precision/imprecision in various registers).

@EdwinAshworth If we want further stipulation for which definitions are in or out of scope it should probably be added to the original question, but personally I don't think it's ambiguous. Taking the position that "the word 'letter' can mean a piece of type rather than a letter in the alphabet" is an interesting reframe, though probably warrants its own answer.

@tchrist the Unicode consortium's authority to maintain the Unicode standard is not established by law or by international treaty (nor is the standard itself).

@tchrist While I think the Unicode consortium's opinion on what is a letter does have a certain amount of authority, alternatively consider what various versions of grep consider to be a letter, such as the underscore, so even within the computing world, the opinion is not consistent.

Finally a simple and correct answer on this site!!

"Someone" is incorrect.
The hyphen does not represent a glottal stop. You have two "words" (sounds). "Uh" and "oh." The hyphen is connecting the compound "word" and isn't always present when writing the phrase. E.G., the phrase can be written "uh-oh" and "uh oh."
The Oxford English Dictionary claims the phrase's first written use was 1925 in the Amarillo Globe (Texas, U.S.A.) newspaper.
For a more detailed discussion of the phrase, see this question.

If the hyphen represented a glottal stop then the correct spelling would be ‑uh‑oh, which it isn't.
The pronunciation of uh oh is the same as the pronunciation of uh-oh.
The vast majority of hyphenated compounds do not contain a glottal stop whatsoever.
The only reasonable conclusion is that the hyphen has nothing to do with pronunciation; it is not a letter; and the fact that its position corresponds with the second of the two glottal stops in uh-oh is just a coincidence.

The glottal stop can actually be a letter in many languages:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop_(letter)
However, in the above articles, the hyphen is never used with this meaning. It would not be completely absurd, for instance, the english word for the !kung people is written with an exclamation mark (to represent an alveolar click), which comes from the IPA letter (and which has now its own Unicode character, different for the exclamation mark).
In this case, my understanding for "uh-oh" is rather that the hyphen is just used to join both words and the fact that there is a glottal stop at this position is just a coincidence. Considering it as a letter seems a bit far-fetched.

The Blackwell Encyclopedia of Writing Systems defines a letter as “a graphic symbol that represents one or more phonemes of a language”.
In other words, letters correspond to sounds - an "A" makes an "ah" sound. What sound does a hyphen make by itself?
Accents or other diacritics aren't letters because despite the fact that they modify the pronunciation, they do not correspond to any phoneme themselves. Even if the argument can be made that a hyphen modifies how a word is pronounced (and I would argue that in this case it doesn't, as "uh oh" without the hyphen is pronounced exactly the same as "uh-oh" with a hyphen), that doesn't make it a letter. The vast majority of people would not associate "-" with any particular sound whatsoever in any circumstance, and the vast majority would not consider it a letter.
Some interesting discourse on what makes a letter may be found here (What is a letter?), trying to disentangle the functional role of a letter from its representation from the very notion of it. Some interesting observations that letters aren't solely defined by their phonetic nature, as letters are still letters when used in mathematical notion, for example. But it seems clear there is a strong link between letters and phonemes, which a hyphen does not have.

His argument is that the hyphen in this word represents the glottal stop (ʔ)

@user619687 Even if it does result in the pronunciation of a glottal stop, that's only by virtue of the surrounding letters. If you wrote "-" alone on a page and asked people what sound it corresponds to, I doubt most would say it's a glottal stop, or any other sound at all. The usual purpose of a letter is to represent a phoneme, but that is not a hyphen's usual purpose. That said, there isn't really a source that unequivocally defines letters which everyone must adhere to for all purposes. But the vast majority of people would not call a hyphen a letter.

'Gnome' has 5 letters as does 'psalm'; letters can be silent. 'B' as a character is pronounced /biː/, and '-' is pronounced /ˈhaɪ.fən/; /// A hyphen appearing in a word  can produce a change in pronunciation (as well as meaning): ('If you re-view the movie, next time you will be able to write a decent review.') So can archetypical ('a'- 'z') letters: 'I hid' / 'I hide'; 'sat' / 'sate'. /// Some archetypical letters double as words; others don't. ///  I fully agree with 'the vast majority would not consider [ "-"] a letter'. But it needs supporting references. From dictionaries, probably.

@EdwinAshworth Silent letters are called such because they are atypical -  there is usually no need to specify that a letter is articulated. That letters are occasionally silent does not mean that they are not usually associated with a phoneme. I specifically mentioned that a hyphens can change pronunciation but that doesn't make them letters. Reference added.

But this shows that 'a graphic symbol that represents one or more phonemes of a language' is at best an incomplete definition. Who knows, from this, whether hyphens should be considered to constitute another anomaly?

Shame! Which one or more phonemes does the 's' represent in that? And which other one or more phonemes does the 'h' represent for? Enough!

@HagenvonEitzen That letters can make many different sounds on their own or in conjunction with other letters, or in some cases even make no sound at all, does not change the simple fact that letters are generally associated with sounds. I'm not saying all letters are always pronounced, or that all non-letters must be aurally undetectable, just that it is usually the case.

While a glottal stop is indeed present in the pronunciation of "Uh-oh," the hyphen itself is not a letter. It's a punctuation mark used to indicate a break or pause in a compound word or phrase. In this case, it helps to visually separate the two syllables and suggests the presence of a glottal stop between them.

If "letter" exclusively referred to a mapping between written characters and phonetics AND if hyphens mapped to a glottal stop with some consistency, then there would be a decent argument for hyphens to be letters.
The reality is that hyphens don't consistently map to any sound, and "letter" is such an overloaded term that there's little hope of using it in any linguistic argument that holds water.
